# Cant find library on import statement in Java Class - Android

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm very new in Android development, and I'm trying to import a library from Github via Gradle. I added a statement in the 'dependencies' section:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
}
```

But I cannot find the library in my Java class when I try to import it:

```
import com.squareup...; //Nothing I put here works.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
}
```

Can somebody point out what I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Try sync grade files  and then save

Comment: u don't need to manually write import.. statement..in android..it automatically imported once u use functions of the library in your code

Comment: @PN10 my bad.. That is the correct answer.

Comment: yeah auto imported they are